# ionic pull up footer extanded by default

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to display by defaut a pull up window without clicking on it. I added default-behavior="show" and state ="expand" but it changed anything. Could you please help me to make this feature which consist in displaying by default the content of the pull up window ?

My code :

```js
<ion-pull-up-footer   max-height="200" class="bar-calm"  default-behavior="EXPANDED">
        <div class="title" ion-pull-up-trigger>See itineraries</div>
        <ion-pull-up-handle width="120" height="15" icon-expand="ion-chevron-up" icon-collapse="ion-chevron-down" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0">
        </ion-pull-up-handle>
        <ion-pull-up-content scroll="false">
      <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-divider">Recent Updates</div>
        <div class="item item-body">
           <div>
             There is a fire in <b>sector 3</b>
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-pull-up-content>
     </ion-pull-up-footer>
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Change default-behviour = "true"
ion-pull footer will work in ionic tags if will written inside the ion-view tag.